# Internalize a String Literal in String Form

Tags: javascript, string, string-literals

Let's say I have the `String` representation of a `String` literal (with escape characters and all); written out as a literal itself, it could look like:

```
'\'Hello,\\tI'm tabbed over!\\n\''
```

How do I internalize this as a `String`, equivalent to the `String` represented by the literal in `String` form; that is, equivalent to what I would get if I just typed

```
'Hello,\tI'm tabbed over!\n'
```

into a program?

I'm aware that I could just use `eval()`, but that seems like a terrible solution. I could be using `eval()` to convert numeric literals in string form to actual numbers, but there are already functions like `Number.parseInt()` for that purpose. Is there anything like this for `String`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var toConvert = "\'Hello,\\tI'm tabbed over!\\n\'";
var str = (new RegExp(toConvert)).toString().replace(/^\/|\/$/g,'');
console.log(str) // 'Hello,\tI'm tabbed over!\n'
```

**update**

There is a much easier solution:

```
"'\'Hello,\\tI'm tabbed over!\\n\'".toString()
```